# Slide up div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I want to create an effect similar to the bbc website where the user will click on the title and then a snippet of content will pop up: http://www.bbc.co.uk/

i have looked all over the place and found this snippet

```
$('.grabPromo').click(function(e){
$('.slideUp').slideToggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8rh/)

I cannot get it to the opposite though? i want the text to slideup rather then down. Any help would be appreciated. if someone can point me in the right direction either using css or Jquery i would be grateful.

I am using it for the captions on the [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in case that helps at all.

What i want before Click:
[image: BBC Before Hover]

What i want it to do on Click:
[image: BBC on hover]

Comment: something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556549/jquery-slidetoggle-from-bottom-to-top?

Comment: Btw the BBC homepage is changing soon, so your reference link will not be relevant soon. Maybe think about taking a screenshot of the effect in action?

Comment: thanks for that @evolutionxbox i have now added screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback:

```
$('.grabPromo').click(function(e){ 
    $('.slideUp').slideDown(300 , function() {
         $(this).slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8rh/858/

In this fiddle you have an example with delay.

Good luck

Comment: Is there any way that i can make the comment appear under the heading like it does on the bbc website. So for instance when You click 'Grab a deal' the text slides up with the content 'what a deal' below?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery UI library

```
$('.grabPromo').click(function(e){
  $('.slideUp').toggle("slide", { direction: 'up' });
});
```

For more information
https://jqueryui.com/effect/